# Manually add ssl sertificate to trusted

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have error

```
curl https://xxx.voxlink.ru                       
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

openssl says next

```
:~# openssl s_client -connect xxx.voxlink.ru:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.voxlink.ru
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.voxlink.ru
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.voxlink.ru
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
...
```

I want manually add root sertificate from chain above to list of trusted and fix ssl error on my server for this host

How can i do it?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but may be this link would help you.
https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation.htm

or you can create your own self signed certificates as well, for that try this:
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215089078-How-to-manually-create-a-CSR-for-a-self-signed-certificate

I have created self signed certificate for one of my applications but haven't done the manual installation of ssl certificates.

Comment: thanks, your links above is about how to install sertificate if i want to serve content from my host with this sertificate.

In my case i want to download without errors from other host with certificate shown above